# Refactoring PL/SQL: many cursors with same rowtype (in theory)

Tags: oracle, generics, plsql, refactoring

I am writing some PL/SQL and found myself falling into a repeptitive pattern:

```
cursor c_curs1 is
   select a, b, c
   from (...) big_subquery_1
   where big_subquery_1.a_ind = 'Y'

cursor c_curs2 is
   select a, b, c
   from (...) big_subquery_2
   where big_subquery_2.b_ind = 'R'

cursor c_curs3 is
   select a, b, c
   from (...) big_subquery_3
   where big_subquery_3.c_ind = 'M'

...
type t_curs1_tab is table of c_curs1;
type t_curs2_tab is table of c_curs2;
type t_curs3_tab is table of c_curs3;
...
v_curs1_results t_curs1_tab := t_curs1_tab();
v_curs2_results t_curs2_tab := t_curs2_tab();
v_curs3_results t_curs3_tab := t_curs3_tab();
```

Then when processing the results, I have code like this:

```
    open c_curs1;
    fetch c_curs1 bulk collect into v_curs1_results;
    close c_curs1;

    if v_curs1_results.first is not null and v_curs1_results.last is not null then
       for i in v_curs1_results.first .. v_curs1_results.last loop
           /*Do something with field a in the results
             Do something with field b in the results
             Do something with field c in the results*/
           ....
       end loop;
    end if;
```

The code in the processing loop is the same for all cursors, as all 3 cursors return `a,b,c` - the only difference being which cursor is referenced. I wanted to refactor this into some sort of generic result-set processor, but I'm stuck here:

```
procedure sp_process_collection(in_collection t_curs1_tab) is ...
```

I can only call this with `v_curs1_results`, I can't call it with `v_curs2_results` or I get a `PLS-00306 wrong number of types or arguments...` compiler error. Is there any way to do this generically so I only have to write one collection processing procedure? I have this pattern of cursor (returning the same three columns, always the same types) appears in several other parts of the same package, and the processing loop, while semantically the same is sometimes written with slightly different code. I'd very much like to centralize the processing in one procedure, I just can'd figure out how to do it in PL/SQL. I know PL/SQL doesn't have generics (Which I *think* would have made a Java/C# solution fairly trivial), but I'm wondering if there's another way to approach this problem that I just haven't thought of.

(using Oracle 10g)

Comment: +1. One of my biggest gripes with PL/SQL!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the resulting columns are the same, there's no reason to have three TYPE declarations. You just have one TYPE. Whether you need one or more variables of that TYPE depends on whether you need to hold the different data sets concurrently.

```
cursor c_curs1 is
   select a, b, c
   from (...) big_subquery_1
   where big_subquery_1.a_ind = 'Y'

cursor c_curs2 is
   select a, b, c
   from (...) big_subquery_2
   where big_subquery_2.b_ind = 'R'

cursor c_curs3 is
   select a, b, c
   from (...) big_subquery_3
   where big_subquery_3.c_ind = 'M'

...
type t_curs_tab is table of c_curs1;
...
v_curs_results t_curs_tab := t_curs_tab();
...
open c_curs1;
fetch c_curs1 bulk collect into v_curs_results;
close c_curs1;
...
open c_curs2;
fetch c_curs2 bulk collect into v_curs_results;
close c_curs2;
...
open c_curs3;
fetch c_curs3 bulk collect into v_curs_results;
close c_curs3;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing and permitted to do so, you can create a `TYPE` to represent a record returned by any of the cursors. For example:

```
CREATE TYPE TRIPLE_TYPE IS OBJECT
(
  a NUMBER,
  b NUMBER,
  c NUMBER
);
```

And another type to hold a collection of `TRIPLE_TYPE`:

```
CREATE TYPE TRIPLES_TYPE IS TABLE OF TRIPLE_TYPE;
```

Finally, you define your cursors to return `TRIPLE_TYPE` records:

```
DECLARE

  cursor c_curs1 is
    select TRIPLE_TYPE(a, b, c)
    from (...) big_subquery_1
    where big_subquery_1.a_ind = 'Y';

  triples TRIPLES_TYPE;

BEGIN
  OPEN c_curs1;
  FETCH c_curs1 BULK COLLECT INTO triples;
  CLOSE c_curs1;
END;
```

This technique allows you to write a procedure that accepts a `TRIPLES_TYPE` collection:

```
procedure sp_process_collection(in_collection TRIPLES_TYPE) is ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you do this with a REF CURSOR?

Something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_process_cursor(in_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR)

/* you don't need to open the cursor, it's already open */
FETCH in_cursor BULK COLLECT INTO v_cursor_results;
IF v_cursor_results.first is not null and v_cursor_results.last IS NOT NULL THEN
  FOR i in v_cursor_results.FIRST .. v_cursor_results.LAST LOOP
  ...
  END LOOP;
END IF;
```

Your calling code would need to invoke this procedure once per cursor:

```
OPEN c_curs1;
sp_process_cursor(c_curs1);
CLOSE c_curs1;

OPEN c_curs2;
sp_process_cursor(c_curs2);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you HAVE to have 3 cursors because the "big_subquery" in each are different I assume.  So, you really just need to centralize a procedure to handle processing a, b, and c results.  Nothing too fancy here, just define a local procedure to do this:

```
CREATE or replace procedure my_proc IS

  cursor c_curs1 is
   select a, b, c
   from (...) big_subquery_1
   where big_subquery_1.a_ind = 'Y';

  cursor c_curs2 is
   select a, b, c
   from (...) big_subquery_2
   where big_subquery_2.b_ind = 'R';

  cursor c_curs3 is
   select a, b, c
   from (...) big_subquery_3
   where big_subquery_3.c_ind = 'M';

  -- local procedure to handle processing of a,b,c "types"
  procedure process_type(i_type in varchar2) is
  begin
    -- do something great here
  end process_type;

BEGIN
  for rec in c_curs1
  loop
    process_type(rec.a);
    -- do something else
    process_type(rec.b);
    -- do something more
    process_type(rec.c);
    -- do something even more
  end loop;

  for rec in c_curs2
  loop
    -- do processing for this cursor
    -- use process_type like above
  end loop;

  for rec in c_curs3
  loop
    -- do processing for this cursor
    -- use process_type like above
  end loop;

END;
```

Of course, if you need to process all 3 types together for each row, or if the types are different (varchar2, date, and number), just modify the process_type procedure to pass in all 3 (a,b,and c).  Something like:

```
procedure process_type(i_type_a in varchar2, i_type_b in date, i_type_c in number) is
  begin
    -- do something great here
  end process_type;
```

And you can make this a function if you need a return value.